# How to connect to Oracle server created by Aws Oracle RDS

Tags: amazon-rds

I created an AWS Oracle RDS and also created a admin user. I want to test connect on this admin account by using command line.

Please help provide any solution to test it. I don't want to use SQL Developer tool to testing

Answer (score 0):

I get your point. To quick test the connect on Oracle, SQL Developer tools is not good choose Because we can need install JDK and SQL Developer tools.

In your case, You can choose Oracle Instant Client to test. It lighter SQL Developer tools. These steps need work to test:

1. Download Basic Package and SQL*Plus Package, prefer link : https://www.oracle.com/cis/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html
   [image]
   [image]
2. Unzip Basic Package and SQL*Plus Package, then copy SQL*Plus Package into Basic Package like that
   [image]
3. Go to the directory of Basic Package, then open command line like that
   [image]
4. Testing connect by command

   sqlplus **youradminname**/**youradminpassword**"//**xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com:1521**/**ORCL**"

Note: please replace the information to your account oracle

```
youradminname => replace to account name which you created 
youradminpassword => replace to password of account which you created 
xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com => replace to your aws oracle rds
1521 => replace if you use difference port
ORCL => replace serivce id/name if you use difference name
```

[image]